# how to apply css on specific td on first tr

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm a beginner in AngularJS, and really want not to use JQuery to solve my problem (maybe I'm wrong).

Here's my problem :

I would like to apply a CSS on the last **td** element in the first **tr** in a table.

My code :

```html
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'name'">
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So for the first **tr**, the last **td** element should be `<td class="myClass">{{person.email}}</td>`

Thanks for your answers and explanations.

Edit : I Forgot to say, I know how to resolve my problem by applying css on the last **td**, but I want to do it with angularjs, because I can have differents **persons**, and depends on the difference, I want to apply another CSS style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular's `ng-class` directive to apply the styles conditionally:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'name'">
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td ng-class="{'myClass':$index==0}">{{person.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Or if you don't want to put id's or classes you can do something like this:

```
table tr:first-child td:last-child {}
```

Note that not all browsers support the child selectors

Answer (score 1):

```
.TABLE-CLASS tr:first-child td:last-child{
   //style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo class -

The :first-child pseudo class means "if this element is the first child of its parent". :last-child means "if this element is the last child of its parent". Note that only element nodes (HTML tags) count, these pseudo-classes ignore text nodes.
So these styles would work for you -

```
table tr td:last-child{
}

table tr td:first-child{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 2 `<td>` in each row you can get around the lack of support for `:last-child` in IE8 by using the CSS `+` selector:

```
table tr:first-child td + td {
  /* styles */
}
```

This will select any `<td>` that is preceded by another `<td>` and is a child of the first `<tr>` of each `<table>`.